# TikZ: Can one combine two nodes with different location on one path into one node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, signal-processing

This question continues my [another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423545/tikz-how-to-automatically-draw-a-rectangle-in-a-rectangle).

My code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
         signal/.style = coordinate,
         sum/.style = {
                       draw,
                       circle,
                       inner sep = 0pt,
                       minimum size = 2mm
                      }
        }

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]

    %placing the nodes
    \node[signal] (input x) {};
    \node[
          sum,
          right = of input x
         ] (sum) {};
    \node[
          signal,
          above=of sum
         ] (input y) {};
    \node[
          signal,
          right=of sum
         ] (output) {};

    %connecting the nodes
    \draw
      [->] (input x) -- node {$x$} (sum);
    \draw
      [->] (input y) -- node {$y$} node[pos = .95] {$-$} (sum);
    \draw
    [->] (sum)       -- node {$z$} (output);

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The question handles this `[->] (input y) -- node {$y$} node[pos = .95] {$-$} (sum);` line. It is possible to reduce this line to one `node` statement, with:

1. Auto labeling for the `y`.
2. The `-` gets its own aligning by `pos = .95`.

Thank you for your effort in advance!

Comment: Combine two nodes in one to do what ? Put the two texts one on top of the other ?

Comment: Hello @Kpym! Thank you for your comment! It is only a question to discover the possibilities for this case. The result should stay the same.

Comment: For me it is not clear what is "this case" : if you move the position of the nodes is it "the same" case ? If you want two nodes at position `.5` and `.95`, you can't combine them in one node that will produce the same output in general.

Comment: Hello @Kpym! Thank you for your comment! Sorry for my unclear english, hope now it's clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

for above image i would write the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, quotes}

\tikzset{sum/.style = {
                       draw,
                       circle,
                       inner sep = 0pt,
                       minimum size = 2mm
                      }
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
%placing the coordinates and node
\coordinate (input x);
\node[sum,right=of input x] (sum) {};
\coordinate[above=of sum] (input y);
\coordinate[right=of sum] (output);
%connecting the nodes
\draw [->]  (input x) edge ["$x$"] (sum)
            (input y) edge ["$y$", "$-$"pos=.95] (sum)
            (sum)      to  ["$z$"] (output);

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the accepted answer, so probably the question was about the "shortest" way to put two nodes on the edge. If this is the case, probably a simpler code will be `edge ["$y$", "$-$"pos=.95]`.

Comment: @Kpym, thank yo very much. now is considered in answer.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you are making it a one-liner. It is not two instructions but two objects collected by TikZ for the same path. Imagine you didn't have this functionality, then it would smell way worse than this when you try to implement more nodes and you would be complaining much harder.

But here you might be better of if you actually specify the junction object (since you smell like a programmer) with proper signal signs.

```
\documentstyle[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{signal/.style = coordinate,
  sum/.style = {draw,circle,inner sep = 0pt,minimum size = 2mm, junction labels/.list={#1}},
  sum/.default={0}{},
  junction labels/.style args={#1/#2}{label={#1:#2}},
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
    %placing the nodes
    \node[signal] (input x) {};
    \node[sum={30/$-$,-130/$+$,-60/$\circ$},right = of input x] (sum) {};
    \node[signal,above=of sum] (input y) {};
    \node[signal,right=of sum] (output) {};

    %connecting the nodes
    \draw[->] (input x) -- node {$x$} (sum);
    \draw[->] (input y) -- node {$y$}  (sum);
    \draw[->] (sum) -- node {$z$} (output);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You smell a bit angry;-) (+1)

Comment: Haha, not really, just following the cue

Comment: Hello @marmot and @percusse! You guys are funny! Anyway thank you for the answer!